# handle media player error gracefully

Tags: android, error-handling, media-player

I am trying to handle a media player error, when the error would occur, I want to toast a message and then play next song , however whenever the error occurs it would just crash.

here is the code I am trying

```
public class player1 extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener,OnErrorListener{
    MediaPlayer mp;
    ArrayList<File> mySongs;
    int position;
    Uri u;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle  b = i.getExtras();
        mySongs = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist");
        position = b.getInt("pos", 0);
        u = Uri.parse(Uri.encode(mySongs.get(position).toString()));
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
        mp.start();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        String errorWhat;
        switch(what){
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                errorWhat = "MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN";
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                errorWhat = "MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED";
                break;
            default:
                errorWhat = "!";
        }

        String errorExtra;
        switch(extra){
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO:
                errorExtra = "MEDIA_ERROR_IO";
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED:
                errorExtra = "MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED";
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED:
                errorExtra = "MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED";
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT:
                errorExtra = "MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT";
                break;
            default:
                errorExtra = "!";
        }

        Toast.makeText(player1.this, 
                "Error" + "\n"
                        + errorWhat + "\n"
                        + errorExtra,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //release
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        initMediaPlayer();

        return true;

    };

    private void initMediaPlayer() {
        Toast.makeText(player1.this, 
            "playomng next song", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        position = (position + 1)%mySongs.size();
        u = Uri.parse(Uri.encode(mySongs.get(position).toString()));
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

How can I manage to handle these errors without forcing the media player to close?

Comment: Since your code crashes, post the stacktrace of the crash to help find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just putting a band aid on your code it may be wiser to find where the actual problem is. If you can find what line(s) you're receiving an error you can simply wrap the code in a

```
try{
     //code that crashes here
} 

catch(Exception e){
  Toast.makeText(context, "Media error", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

EDIT:
Be aware that simply preventing a crash via a try/catch can cause bugs itself. If you can post your logcat we may be able to figure out what your actual error is.

Answer (score 0):

- Without logcat we can not say much, however you did not set the
  player to listen to the errors `mp.setOnErrorListener(this);`.
- I think your crash might be `i.getExtras();` it can be null, therefore calling `b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist");` might just crash your application.